# What is the Best way for Authentication/Authorization in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, authentication, authorization

We have a SL application and many users who use this system with different data and access roles. For example, each user can have some devices and each device will send its locations every 5 minutes to server.

One approach is defining a User table in database and have many tables which connect an entity to a user Id, but this is not a good idea as that creates many tables between users and other entities.

It will be a time consuming process to select user data or reporting, so I wanted to know what the best way is for handling such behavior in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

You can use AuthenticationDomainService. This is a popular service for authorization users with roles. You can get more information there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707361(v=VS.91).aspx

Comment: I know about this technology but, I meant in my database. AuthenticationDomainService has User table in database also. Am I right? So, if I want to save some data for a specific user in database I must use a middle table between user and my data table.