# Allowing user to IIS Authorization roles from Web.config

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, silverlight, authorization

I'm working on an Silverlight/ WPF application and I am trying to allow certain user´s to access the website. 
Is it possible to Allow users by using a Textbox to enter the user's name? This will then be parsed to *IIS .NET authorization rules* to allow that specific user access.

For example if I input the users name here.[image]

I want that to get sent to here...

```
 <system.web>
<roleManager enabled="false" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="AX/Axxxxxx"/>
```

I'm guessing I need to write the syntax in the xaml.cs file?
Where it needs to check for a correct value in the textbox and then proceed to complete the autorization once i click the OK button.

Can I do for example

`if (UserNameBox.text.Contains("AX\A") )
 { do something...
 }`

I'm thinking of only checking those first 4 letters as the others are random numbers. 
Is this possible and how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex matter which i find hard to answer short. But one thing is for sure, you should never have any username or password checks in the silvelight code, except for cosmetics. Your should pass the credentials to the server/api and do the checking there. Otherwise it is easy for any hacker to circumvent your protection.

As it looks like you are on a Windows domain, you don't really need to collect the username. This is already passed on in every request to the server in the kerberos token. If you turn on windows authentication on the server you can pick up the username here Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name or similar depending on what stack your api is.

There is another SO post similar to this: 
[What is the Best way for Authentication/Authorization in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698551/what-is-the-best-way-for-authentication-authorization-in-silverlight)

Comment: Thank you for this, I will check it out and try and follow with your tips.

Comment: Is it not possible to add them by code into the web.config file somehow? I dont think i fully understand how your answer could solve my issue..?

Comment: It wasn't ment to solve it, rather than nudge you in the right direction. Do you have your users in AD? How you can configure access control depends a lot on what kind of backend you have.